# What is the reason for var $this = this

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, this

I'm not the best at jquery and I came across a var initialization that I don't know why the person who wrote the code did it this way.

In the init for a plugin, we have

```
this.init = function(settings) {
    var $this = this;
    this.s = {
        initialSlide: 0,
        firstSlide: true,
    };
   ... more code, some uses $this, some uses "this"
}
```

So what is the difference here between "$this" and "this" and why not use one or the other all the time?

Comment: yes it does, it is a jquery idiom

Comment: @Matt: There is no jQuery in the code. Assigning `this` to another variable is also very common in "plain JavaScript".

Comment: @Felix: It is a plugin, which means that this refers to a jquery object. There is (or used to be) a jquery idiom to prefix jquery objects with $. hence, its a jquery question. If it were non jquery, instead of $this you would probably see, that, self, or something more descriptive as to what this actually means

Comment: @Matt: Oh... *In the init for a plugin*.... I missed that part. NVM.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Generally, this means a copy of `this`. The thing about `this` is that it changes within each function. Storing it this way, however, keeps `$this` from changing whereas `this` does change.

jQuery heavily uses the magic `this` value.

Consider this code, where you might need something like you are seeing:

```
$.fn.doSomethingWithElements = function() {
    var $this = this;

    this.each(function() {
        // `this` refers to each element and differs each time this function
        //    is called
        //
        // `$this` refers to old `this`, i.e. the set of elements, and will be
        //    the same each time this function is called
    });
};
```

Comment: for older version of jQuery how do you write $this ? jQuerythis??

Comment: var $this is just as any other variable name, the $ and this is just a way to keep another person who reads the code to know what the variable does further down the page. In short terms, yes you could write `var jQuerythis` but that doesnt really makes any difference. You can use $ in older jQuery aswell, as stated above the $this isnt jQuery dependent, it's just a way to create a copy of `this`.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, nothing. `$this` is just another variable declaration which has `this` assigned to it.

Typically, I've seen this shortcut used by people using JavaScript libraries when wrapping `this`. For example, typical usage in jQuery would be:

```
// rather than writing $(this) everywhere
var $this = $(this);

$this.each(function(){
    // Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In actuality jQuery is a wrapper around the JavaScript DOM, both enhancing and simplifying it. 
Very briefly JQuery selectors return JQuery Object/s i.e.

```
var jQueryResults = $("article"); //Contains all article elements in the DOM as JQuery objects
```

However, selecting elements with Javascript returns HTML DOM elements i.e.

```
var normalResults = document.getElementsByTagName("article");//Contains all article elements in the DOM as HTML objects
```

The issues arise in that DOM objects do not provide the same functionality that JQuery objects provide.

Here is an event example which illustrates the difference:

```
$('.changeColorHover').hover(function() {
    this.attr("style", "color:red");
}); //Will not work as we are trying to call a JQuery method on a DOM object
```

With the above mentioned in mind the 'this' keyword is a DOM object and thus you are required to convert it to a jQuery object in order to utilise jQuery methods.

```
 $('.changeColorHover').hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("style", "color:red");
 }); //Will work since we have first converted the DOM object to a JQuery object
```

To sum up, the this keyword, allows you to access the object that called the event as this will give a reference to the object that raised the event. But, this is a DOM object, not a jQuery object. As a result, any of the jQuery methods you'd like to use aren't available, unless you convert it to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

It means nothing in this case (no pun intended). It would be more logical if the statement was `var $this = $(this)` since that would allow for all the nice jQuery functionality to be used.

Comment: Incorrect, reassigning this to a different variable allows inner closures to reference the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

What everyone else said, also there is an idiom in jquery code to prefix jquery objects with $. don't know how popular it is any more, but used to see a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

I do $this = $(this) because it seems that it would save the actual processing of that call every single time you want to use it.

Also, for the 'magic 'this'' function that someone else mentioned. It is handy to keep the original copy around.