# why assign $(this) to a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the reason for var $this = this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234282/what-is-the-reason-for-var-this-this)

Why should $(this) be scoped within a function? What benefits does it offer over referencing $(this) directly?

## Example:

```
function Name(){
    var $this = $(this)
}
```

Comment: How is $this being used later? If in another scope, `$(this)` might point elsewhere.

Comment: 1- To avoid repetition and calling `$()` everytime. 2- To cache the value of `this` to use it in deeper scopes.

Comment: IMO a better duplicate thread is http://stackoverflow.com/q/5724400/1331430

Comment: But basically, scoping & performance are the reasons which are explained in detail on the possible duplicate and on my link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` function *builds* a jQuery object from the value(s) passed into it. If you constantly call it over and over again, you're building the same thing over and over again. Many people instead choose to *cache* the result, so as to avoid repetitiveness.

Comment: Thank you for the very coherent response. I was really confused trying to understand the benefit of a cached version but you cleared it up perfectly.