# What is the reasoning behind declaring var that = this; in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this many times in a new code base that I'm looking at and was wondering is there is any proper reasoning behind it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234282/what-is-the-reason-for-var-this-this?rq=1

Comment: Take the code, and try to substitute `this` for `that` where used, and you'll see that it likely won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4886696/1651233

Comment: Thanks everyone. Not sure why the previously asked question didn't show up in my initial search for an answer to this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `var that = this;` is order to keep a reference to current `this` object, when later `this` will be pointing to something else.

Example ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886696/1651233)):

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    // this is a reference to the element clicked on

    var that = this;

    $('.elements').each(function(){
        // this is a reference to the current element in the loop
        // that is still a reference to the element clicked on
    });
});
```

Comment: Same as my answer, but with an example, well played :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the meaning of `this` in JavaScript changes based on the scope.  `this` inside of a constructor means something different than `this` inside of a function.  Here's a [good article](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to "this" outside/inside of the scope of a specific function call where what "this" is may have changed.  Just one example I can think of.